# How to use count() method in Firestore transaction?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a callable cloud function (node.js) which runs a transaction with numerous writes and reads. One of those reads should be a [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) read:

```
const count = await transaction.get(db.collection("posts").count());
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as I get an error. Perhaps this method isn't yet a part of transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for `count()` queries was added in [`firebase-admin@11.2.0`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1120_-_17_october_2022) and [`transaction.get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) takes either a `DocumentReference` or a `Query` (also `AggregateQuery`) so that should work. Try updating to latest version of `firebase-admin`.

```
npm i firebase-admin@latest
```

Comment: Thx, if you're usign `pnpm` the command will be `pnpm i firebase-admin@latest`